# How to visualize surface normals as Marker::Arrow for each point in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to show the surface normals of a point cloud in rviz. Below is what I was trying:

- Create a MarkerArray and corresponding publisher
- Resize the MarkerArray with the size of the point cloud to be visualized (25344 points in this case) at the very first
- Assign frame_id, ns, id, type, action, color for each marker just once
- update position of the arrows with the point cloud at each iteration
- update markers scales with the point cloud normal data at each iteration
- publish the markerarray

Whenever it publishes the markerarray, RAM blows up and swap is heavily used and PC stalls there.

What do you think I am doing very badly wrong here? Or isn't it possible to visualize that many arrows (25344 of them) in the rviz? If so, should I use other tools coming with PCL?

Thanks a lot...

-Kadir-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9095/how-to-visualize-surface-normals-as-marker::arrow-for-each-point-in-rviz?/) by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-02-17**:
Hi Kadir,

we did it with MarkerArray message but it also choked up rviz a bit. You can have a look at our code here: http://code.cs.tum.edu/indefero/index.php//p/mapping/source/tree/master/pcl_cloud_tools/src/pcl_normal_visualization.cpp

D.

**Comment by [chinmay_sujir](https://answers.ros.org/users/126422/chinmay_sujir/) on 2023-01-11**:
The above link doesn't work. Any chance you still have this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is very likely that rviz chokes up because of the amount of markers. I think each arrow is a separate 3D object. I would recommend using the pcl visualization tool:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_visualization

You can use the existing PointNormal data type, defined here:

http://www.ros.org/doc/api/pcl/html/point__types_8h_source.html

Since you already have the algorithm to calculate the normals, all you have to do is build a pcl cloud and fill out the fields. Here's the nice part about using pcl - you can set how many normals you want to display - for example, one every 10 or 20 points. This should make it much quicker.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1